# Faraday's Law (General form) and the Change in flux

Tags: homework-and-exercises, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, maxwell-equations, electromagnetic-induction

For the Introductory E&M class, I am taking this year I was working on some problems involving the general Faraday's Law
$$\oint{E.dS}=-\frac{d\phi_B}{dt}$$

I was confused regarding, How we interpret the flux on the right-hand side of the equation?

**Here are the problems:**

1. A magnetic field directed into the page changes with time according to $B=0.030t^2+1.40$, where B is in teslas and t is in seconds. The field has a circular cross-section of radius $R=2.50$ cm. When $t=3.00$ s and $r_2=0.02$ m, what are (a) the magnitude and (b) the direction of the electric field at point $P_2$? [Here is the attached diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77GsV.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77GsV.png)
2. A long solenoid with $1.00\times10^3$ turns per meter and radius $2.00$ cm carries an oscillating current   $I=5.00 \sin (100\pi t)$, where $i$ is in amperes and $t$ is in seconds. (a) What is the electric field induced at a radius $r=1.00$ cm from the axis of the solenoid?

**My approach:**

1)Point $P_2$ lies inside the region of the uniform magnetic field. The rate of change of the field, in teslas per second, is $\frac{dB}{dt}=0.060t$, now the magnetic flux is increasing into the page; therefore, by the righthand rule (see figure), the induced electric field lines are
counterclockwise. The electric field at point P2 is tangent to the electric field line passing through it. Now I will use $\oint{E.dS}=-\frac{d\phi_B}{dt}$; here is where i am confused. The book we use has written $\frac{d\phi_B}{dt}=\frac{dB}{dt}*\pi R^2$, i.e. they used the entire radius of the magnetic field region, R, in calculating the change in flux through the point $P_2$ inside the region and they used the radius $r_2$ to get the circumference of the path of integration for the $E$ term. *However*, in this solved [exam](https://users.wfu.edu/%7Eshapiro/Phy11413/Exam3sol12.pdf) [pg-10,problem 4A], they used $r_2$ to get both the path of integration and to calculate the flux[$B*\pi r_2^2$].

*This had me confused. Which radius will we normally use in such situations? Do we use the entire radius of the field for the flux and then the radius,$r_2$, up to the interior point $P_2$ to get the path as in the method in my book, or do we use the interior radius to get both area and path?*

2)in [example 13.5.2](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/University_Physics/Book%3A_University_Physics_(OpenStax)/Map%3A_University_Physics_II_-_Thermodynamics_Electricity_and_Magnetism_(OpenStax)/13%3A_Electromagnetic_Induction/13.05%3A_Induced_Electric_Fields#:%7E:text=An%20electric%20field%20is%20induced%20both%20inside%20and%20outside%20the%20solenoid.&text=Using%20the%20formula%20for%20the,we%20calculate%20the%20induced%20emf.&text=The%20magnetic%20field%20is%20confined,I0e%E2%88%92%CE%B1t.) here, and my book, we've used the radius given[inside solenoid] to get the path of integration and to calculate the flux- That is we are using a single value of the distance from the solenoid's axis to get both the flux through the region enclosed by the loop as well as the path of integration around this said loop; we didn't even use the radius of the solenoid to get the flux through the entire region of the field as is the case with my book in the previous problem. These $2$ problems seemed contradictory to me and would appreciate some input to help clear these two cases.

Comment: Regarding 1). @Prateek_Hegde already gave the correct answer. I would advice to understand your equations better. $\oint E.dS$ is meaningless unless you state the contour that you are integrating. And that contour also defines which area is the area for finding flux.

Comment: Also instead of giving links to outside resources, which may over time vanish, please bring all the explanation here.

Comment: @Cryo ahh i see, The thing about doing Calc.3 and E&M concurrently is that i still need a bit more time for all the multivariable stuff to set in stone before i can understand the Physics equations even more deeply. Hopefully, by next semester i would be able to mitigate this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use smaller radius if that's how large the field extends. It is the integral of B.ds over the surface. So if B is zero outside a circle then it won't contribute to magnetic flux.

Comment: But B is not zero outside the circle of radius r2. However,  as the integration contour has radius r2, the surface delimited by the contour should also have radius r2. See comment by Cryo.

Comment: i see, so in $\oint E.dS=-\frac{d\phi_B}{dt}$ the path we use to evaluate the left side also encloses an area and it is that enclosed area that we use for the right side, right? Looks like the text-book made an error in this case. I've understood now.